# Преобразование json

Tags: java, json, android-studio

Как разобрать json такого вида:

```
{
    "firstName": "login",
    "contractData": [
        {
            "contract": "10000555555",
            "contractDate": "28.03.2018"
        }
    ]
}
```

запрос pojo щас выглядит так

класс Example

```
    @SerializedName("firstName")
    @Expose
    public String firstName;
    @SerializedName("contractData")
    @Expose
    public List<ContractDatum> contractData = new ArrayList<ContractDatum>();

    public Example withFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        return this;
    }

    public Example withContractData(List<ContractDatum> contractData) {
        this.contractData = contractData;
        return this;
    }   
}
```

класс ContractDatum

```
public class ContractDatum {

    @SerializedName("contract")
    @Expose
    public String contract;
    @SerializedName("contractDate")
    @Expose
    public String contractDate;

    public ContractDatum withContract(String contract) {
        this.contract = contract;
        return this;
    }

    public ContractDatum withContractDate(String contractDate) {
        this.contractDate = contractDate;
        return this;
    }
}
```

для получения firstName вызываю так

```
textView.append(example.firstName + "\n");
```

не понимаю как получить данные по ключам из contractData

Comment: Пркобразуйте json в массив и вытягивайте из него всё что захотите.

Comment: А где тут сложный json?)

Comment: для вас может быть и не чего, вы с рождения видимо могли разбирать такие запросы уже ?

Comment: @LEON в чем сложность данного запроса?

Comment: Как уже написали преобразуйте  json в массив и вытягивайте из него всё что захотите, главное тут правильно составить pojo. Тут надо как бы весь запрос обернуть в класс. Например создать класс Responce.  И доставать примерно так: responce.getFirstName  а во втором случае responce.getContractData().getContract()

Comment: `textView.append(example.contractData.get(0).contract + "\n");` - для примера, вывод поля `contract` первого в списке `contractData`

Comment: Спасибо большое все заработало)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто...
Использую Gson, lombok, зависимости для градла прилагаю:

compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.6'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Main {

    private final static Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateAdapter())
        .create();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String json = "{\n" +
"    \"firstName\": \"login\",\n" +
"    \"contractData\": [\n" +
"        {\n" +
"            \"contract\": \"10000555555\",\n" +
"            \"contractDate\": \"28.03.2018\"\n" +
"        }\n" +
"    ]\n" +
"} ";

        JsonData fromJson = GSON.fromJson(json, JsonData.class);

        System.out.println(fromJson);
        //System.out.println(Long.valueOf(fromJson.getContractData()[0].getContract()));
        //System.out.println(fromJson.getContractData()[0].getContractDate());
    }
}

import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class LocalDateAdapter extends TypeAdapter<LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter jsonWriter, final LocalDate localDate) throws IOException {
        jsonWriter.value(localDate.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate read(final JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
        return LocalDate.parse(jsonReader.nextString(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy"));
    }

}

@lombok.Data
public class JsonData {
    private String firstName;
    private ContractData[] contractData;
}

import java.time.LocalDate;

@lombok.Data
public class ContractData {    
    private Long contract; 
    private LocalDate contractDate;

}
```